# Add data sets with xmgrace

Tags: plot, xmgrace

I use xmgrace to plot data sets and I would like to add two data sets together.

So I have two files:

*data1*

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
...
```

*data2*

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
...
```

I start xmgrace with

```
xmgrace data1 data2
```

Then I see both files plotted. Now I would like to generate a third graph which is just data1+data2 like

```
1 3
2 7
3 13
...
```

I know that this is extremely simple, but for some reason I don't understand how that works.

I played with the feature Data->Transformations->Evaluate expression... but I don't know what to select as "Source" and as "Destination".

PS: I know many other ways to reach my goal but I also want to be able to do it with xmgrace.

Answer (score 5):

This can easily be achieved using the feature `Evaluate expression...`

```
xmgrace data1 data2
```

Click on `Data`->`Transformations`->`Evaluate expression...`

Select any one (say `G0.S0`) of the two sets (`G0.S0` and `G0.S1`) as the source. Do not select any existing set as the destination if you want the output to a new set. The Formula should read

```
y=g0.s0.y+g0.s1.y
```

The `evaluateExpression` window should look like

[image: Selections]

When you `Apply`, a new set (`G0.S3`) will be created. You can modify the formula (`g1` for graph `G1`, etc.) to add values across different graphs as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
xmgrace data1 data2
```

Go to  <kbd>window</kbd> > <kbd>commands</kbd>

Type in the following commands one by one.

```
s2 length s0.length
s2.x = s0.x # Change s0.x to s0.x+s1.x if you want to add x too.
s2.y = s0.y+s1.y
redraw
updateall
```

You can also add these commands into a `add.com` file and save it in the same directory as the data file.

Then
<kbd>window</kbd> > <kbd>commands</kbd> > <kbd>Read...</kbd> > (load `add.com`) > <kbd>Replay</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Sathyam's answer is great if you don't mind using the xmgrace GUI, but if you want to do everything on the commandline there are a number of ways.

**Answer:**
Here is one way to do it:

`paste -d ' ' data1 data2 | awk '{print $1,$2+$4}' | xmgrace -pipe data1 data2`

**Step-by-step explanation:**
First we horizontally stack the two files using the `paste` command:

`paste -d ' ' data1 data2`

This gives the folowing output:

```
1 1 1 2
2 4 2 3
3 9 3 4
```

Then we pipe this to `awk` to print the first column and to do an element-wise sum of columns 2 and 4:

`paste -d ' ' data1 data2 | awk '{print $1,$2+$4}'`

This gives:

```
1 3
2 7
3 13
```

Now we want to pipe this on to xmgrace and then provide the original data files as additional data sets.

`paste -d ' ' data1 data2 | awk '{print $1,$2+$4}' | xmgrace -pipe data1 data2`

Note that the piped data is still in the third data set "S2" because the piped data gets processed last, as xmgrace is loaded.

Here is the output (after I made it look a little prettier):

[image]